# Python - Specify arguments' data type

Tags: python, casting

To keep things simplistic, consider the Python function:

```
def to_string(value):
    return str(value)
```

Since we cannot define data types of parameters in Python (as for as I know), when I pass `1/2` to above function, it automatically converts `1/2` to `0.5` and then returns string `'0.5'`. How do I make it return `'1/2'`? How do I force Python to treat arguments to be of certain data type, no matter how they "appear"?

Comment: Python's names (variables, arguments, function names...) don't have types. Values have types. The calculation `1/2` is performed and `0.5` is the result, which has the type `float`; and all of this happens *before the function is called*.

There are "annotations" you can use to indicate the intended types for things, and tools that will do a bit of static analysis to try to enforce this. But you cannot make `1/2` result in something other than `0.5`, and you cannot make `0.5` be something other than a `float`.

It would help to have a better understanding of *why you want to do this*.

Comment: Because of the name `fraction` in your example, it comes across like what you *really* want to do is to be able to represent rational numbers (fractions) in your code, see the numerator and denominator, and also evaluate them to a floating-point value. For this, [use the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fractions.html).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have renamed `fraction` to `value`.

Comment: I am actually creating a class whose `__init__()` method reads a fraction as a _fraction_ and performs various fraction based arithmetics on it, in _non-decimal_ format. The way we used to do in primary school.

Comment: Yes, the built-in standard library class that I linked to can do this for you.

Comment: I know I am pushing my luck but the `fractions` library accepts fractions as `Fraction(11, 10)`, which seems a little unnatural. I wish it could accept them as `11/10`.

Comment: You can do `Fraction('11/10')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here (in python 3) 1/2 is evaluated to 0.5 before being even passed into the function. For this specific example you have lost the information, due to possible float accuracy errors, before the function is even called; In theory you can get back to 1/2 from 0.5 but you should not rely on this float manipulation. In order to not lose this accuracy here you should probably treat a fraction as two pieces of integer information as it really is, instead of one float.

```
from fractions import gcd

def to_string(n, d):
    g = gcd(n, d)
    return str(n//g) + "/" + str(d//g)
```

If what you are asking is specifically about fractions then a class built around this idea is probably your best bet. If your example is not explanatory then (famously) python does not have type enforcement. However you can read here https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html about modernisation of this idea and decorators.

Comment: This is a good trick and I appreciate it. However, my requirement has always been reading the fraction _like_ a fraction. If my requirements allowed reading two arguments, I could just as easily call `Fractions(n, d)` method from `fractions` library.

Comment: The only way to do this then is to pass as the string "1/2" and split on "/". 1/2 will evaluate before the function as stated before